# How do I find the reciprocal of a fraction in C?

Tags: c

I am making calculator for physics, but when I was coding the focal length equation I needed to find the reciprocal of the fraction found for the focal length.

Comment: Hm. Divide `1` by it?

Comment: `reciprocal = 1.0/fraction;`  If this is not sufficient, you need to post more to add clarity.

Comment: Please explain more. Maybe give pairs of sample input and desired output.

Comment: @Peytuk and Ben Thank you for helping the code did work as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double eqn_reciprocal= pow(eqn,-1);
```

this would do the trick

Comment: Don’t do this. `pow` is a heavyweight function. Even if it has a fast internal path for exponent -1, it is overkill. Even if the compiler optimzes it, `1./number` is simpler source code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil of course `/number` is way more simple, but apparently that's not exactly what he/she wants. Otherwise this would be nothing but a simple math question.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're making a physics calculator and want to find the reciprocal of something, you'd just have to use the pow() function.
In C, I think it would look something like this:

```
reciprocal = pow(number, -1); //number is the number you want to find the reciprocal of.
```

Please comment if this didn't answer your question.

Comment: Don’t do this. `pow` is a heavyweight function. Even if it has a fast internal path for exponent -1, it is overkill. Even if the compiler optimzes it, `1./number` is simpler source code.